# Matplotlib colorbar ticks disappear with large range

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm having a strange issue with the colorbar and a large clim range. My images/data span many orders of magnitude. When I have a range from 10^-9 to 1. There are no problems, and my colorbar has ticks and tick labels as normal. When my range extends to 10^-10 and below, the ticks and tick labels disappear. Is this a known issue? Please see some example code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib import colors

fig = plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(10,7), dpi=240)
fig.clf()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
img = ax.imshow( image, cmap='nipy_spectral', norm=colors.LogNorm(), clim=(10**-10,1) )
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('')
ax.set_title('')
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="3%", pad=0.1)
fig.colorbar(img, cax=cax)
fig.show()
fig.savefig('filename.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Also, this is the code block I normally use for generating figures, with obvious changes for subplots, etc. Is it overkill, or does it seem reasonable?

Thank you!